# How to resolve unable to find valid certification path to requested target exception?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, ws-security

I am getting this exception "unable to find valid certification path to requested target". I know there are so many online solutions but none fit my situation. I got the entry in the server argument as `Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\SSL\myFile.jks` but still getting the same exception. I am deploying the app in my local DEV environment. Is there any other way to debug this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer to my question. I wasn't enclosing the path with "" which solved my issue.